# Does the pitch of ある ever change?

Tags: pitch-accent

**Context:** I've come across the sentence

> そんなわけあるはずない

which I'm assuming parses into

> (そんな)(わけ)(ある)(はずない)

and means something like

> That sort of reason existing cannot be!

or more idiomatically:

> That cannot be!

**Problem:** When I put this sentence into [OJAD](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/eng/phrasing/index) I get

> [image]

with ある{LH}.  But I thought ある had pitch ある{HL}? If I use 有る in place of ある with OJAD (just to make it extra precise), the problem persists.

**Question:** Does the pitch of ある ever change in contexts like this? I know that OJAD sometimes gets things wrong, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: I think you should simply stop relying on that tool for anything more than the pitch of an individual word.

Comment: When I put in ある into that tool, I get the opposite, that is, high-low, so I am not sure what you mean. In general, I think the pitch of ある tends to be relatively flat...

Comment: The pitch of ある is not “relatively flat”…

Comment: I think you shouldn't worry about pitch at all...

Comment: @istrasci +1, I would put pitch alongside kanji readings in the bag of  "learn them by exposure"

Comment: @istrasci , jarmanso7: -1, there are basically zero cases of someone coming from a stress-accent language that picked up JP pitch accent to a high level without significant direct work. If someone cares about being highly intelligible and pleasant to listen to, it’s very worth focusing on early-on. Sure, not *everyone* cares about that, but some do, and one should not deny their efforts.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie:  I've mentioned this before, but my first semester of Japanese 25 years ago, my teacher said "don't worry about pitch accent".  And I've ***never*** had an issue with it.  And I did not deny OPs effort; I gave my opinion.  If they want to delve into pitch, that's their prerogative, but I personally don't feel that it's worth it.  They can do with that what they will...

Comment: “I’ve never had an issue with it”. Do you think that is because you managed to naturally acquire it, or you didn’t and it just isn’t an issue? It tends to become in issue in complex, low-context situations. E.g., if you work using JP professionally and are giving a presentation on a complex topic, or are an interpreter, etc, pitch mistakes regularly do cause difficulties in comprehension. You can take my word on this because I see it happen regularly. Most people won’t point it out, so if you are orienting based on some sort of expected feedback, it is likely missing.

Comment: Given that the comment section here is very difficult to have extended conversations in, and the fact it is difficult to share audio, I don’t expect to be able to have a fruitful discussion here, but as you can probably tell from my regular answers on the topic, I have quite a bit of specialty in it, and am pretty good at evaluating what sort of issues ppl have in the area and exactly the impact it has on their comprehensibility. I’d be happy to go in more detail somewhere with higher bandwidth.